# System.string[] / listbox problems VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

im fairly new to VB.NET, im trying to work out why its coming up with System.string[] in the first part of the code down below, and also in the 2nd part im wondering why the value is coming up 4x4 times

Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Colours() As String = {"Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"}

        For Each item As String In Colours
            Console.WriteLine(Colours)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also if i try it will a listbox, it will add each item but it will do it 4x4 times.

So for example it will add "Red" four times to the list.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Colours() As String = {"Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"}

        For Each item As String In Colours
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Colours)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

thanks again, not too sure if i can ask 2 questions at the same time but i figured since they are sorta the same question, it would be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Colours` use the actual `item`:

```
For Each item As String In Colours
    ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Same with your `Console.WriteLine`

```
For Each item As String In Colours
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

Comment: thanks mate :) I should have guessed, i also tried this for the console side, and by adding "Items" it worked too, thanks again mate :)